# Implement web services using SSO and Custom Security for Reporting Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, reporting-services

Is there a way to implement web services using SSO and Custom Security for Reporting Service? I am inexperienced and I am afraid I couldn't get into right direction if I keep reading without any insight. So, experts please give me a hand. My interested language to use is C#. I am using Sql server 2012 and Visual Studio 2012. 
What I've tried so far: Form Authentication in Reporting Services from codeplex.

Comment: What do you actually want to do? Do you want to display a SSRS report inside a C# app?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid  Sorry for my late reply. Yup, the main concept underneath is displaying SSRS report inside a C# app.it is. But I have two scenarios in my mind, S1: I have several reports deployed into my report server. I want users to be able to access without using any AD accounts. Those users will be given different types of access.The users will be log in with their credentials at least for the first time, for subsequent logins, they don't need to provide theirs anymore.

Comment: S2:( I guess it is more simpler though I have missing pieces to implement this) The users can access to my reports -(view and print only) from different machine. The admin right will be only given to me -(including edit).  But again, I don't want to use any AD accounts for this. I am aware that using AD or inside same network/domain, I can easily achieve it just by simply using Reporting Service with Window Authentication. But, I don't want to include any AD or Domain accounts when granting access to users. Thanks.

Comment: This: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms154673.aspx shows you how to set login/password explicitly when accessing SSRS reports. You need to hard code windows credentials here to run reports. Then you need to wrap all of that up in your own authorisation scheme inside your app. This is a bad idea. Do you have a good reason to not use windows authentication.

Comment: Thanks for the link @Nick.McDermaid Mainly because I was asked to implement without any AD setting involved. Though, the more I read, I more I am in strong belief on window authentication has best security control. By the way, can you elaborate more on hard coding window credentials to run report and that mentioned wrapping inside own authorisation.

Comment: SSRS is intrinsically linked with AD. You can't install it without AD (service accounts). Access to reports is ascertained via AD. Nothing you've said explains why you don't want to use AD. To _not_ use AD is far more work than using AD. I'd prefer not to explain my brief comment further as it's a bad idea.

Comment: So, why [Form Authentication on the Report Server] (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-sg/library/cc281383.aspx) ?

Comment: Forms authentication basically forces a user to log with login/pwd rather than automatically logging on using windows credentials. This is useful for example when the user comes in from the internet and can't log on to AD. Take note of the warnings and notes in that article about complexity. If for example it was going to take a year to implement this, and it would also require a part time employee to maintain, would that still be worth it against the requirements?

Comment: Regardless, without any code or background info, this is a _big_ thing that cannot be answered here. First you need to architect it (where will you store these logins/passwords? in a database?), then you need to write some code then we can help with code.